# Spring Data Elastic search not sorting list correctly in Java

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have the following data.

```
Product
A-DC1
ssss
A-DC3
A-DC2
```

I have the following method:

```
public List<Product> searchAndSort(String search, Pageable pageable) {
   List<Product> productList = null;

   if (search != null && !search.equals("")) {
     ((BoolQuerBuilder)(qb)).must((Querybuilders.matchQuery("product", search)));
   }

   NativeSearchQueryBuilder ns = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
   ns.withQuery(qb);
   ns.withPageable(pageable);
   ns.withSearchType(SearchType.QUERY_THEN_FETCH);

   productList = productRep.search(ns);

   return productList;
}
```

The pageable parameter has the sort value of "product,asc" for ascending and "product,desc" for descending.

When I sort by ascending, I get the following:

```
A-DC1
A-DC2
A-DC3
ssss
```

When I sort by descending, I get the following:

```
A-DC1
ssss
A-DC2
A-DC3
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Also, is there a way to do alphanumeric/natural sort in elastic? I.E. If I have Pr 1, Pr 2, Pr 3, Pr 10
I want it to show in the following order:

```
Pr 1
Pr 2
Pr 3
Pr 10
```

Currently, it shows:

```
Pr 1
Pr 10
Pr 2
Pr 3
```

Comment: what is `qb`? What is passed in as value for _search_?

Comment: qb = queryBuilder